# Install Gnome in Debian in VM of MACOS

Tags: linux, debian

I have tried to install Gnome in by using this below code

> apt-get install aptitude tasksel
>   tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install

When Instaling packages it get failed:

```
tasksel apt-get failed(100)
```

Comment: Your question does not seem suitable for the StackOverflow site. Maybe it is better suited for superuser.com. Also, a little more information on the error will definitely be needed

Comment: have you tried `apt-get install gnome-desktop`?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem #1 - Held packages**

It could be because you have some packages which are held and cause conflicts with new version of Gnome you are trying to install. please run following command

```
# apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

if it tells you something about such conflicts feel free to run the following command

```
# aptitude
```

and press g and that will list the packages to be removed press g once more to perform the removal. 
now try again the following

```
# tasksel gnome-desktop
```

**Problem #2 Low disk space**
You might be having low disk space in your partition mounted as / (root) run the following to check

```
# df -h
```

if the available space is too less, you can manually free some space if possible. Also run the following to free up some more space

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get autoremove
```

and then retry `tasksel gnome-desktop`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before downloading anything, you should update your package database with:

```
# apt-get update
```

Then try to

```
# apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

Remember that you should run all apt-get commands as root.

Comment: Tried this code get installed but finally got Error  "E:Sub-Process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: I had space error on device so i increase the space and run the command it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this article http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html to install Gnome in Debian

Aptitude is an Ncurses based FrontEnd to Apt, the debian package manager.

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```